# Get MySQL data in node.js (express) and print using EJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm trying to get the data of my MySQL table and print them in HTML using EJS, but this doesn't work. It tells me `print not defined`. What should I do?

```
router.get('/data', function(req, res){
    res.render('print', {req : req, res : res});
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users', function(err, result) {

        if(err){
            throw err;
        } else {
            for(x in result){
                res.locals.print =  result[x];
                console.log(result[x]);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <%= print %>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the render, you can return a JSON variable with the consulted data and show in the view. `res.render`  can be the last instruction in this way. Some like this:

```
var obj = {};
router.get('/data', function(req, res){

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users', function(err, result) {

        if(err){
            throw err;
        } else {
            obj = {print: result};
            res.render('print', obj);                
        }
    });

});
```

```
<body>
    <table id="table" >  
        <thead>  
            <tr>  
                <th>Username</th>  
                <th>Password</th>  
            </tr>  
        </thead>  
         <tbody>  
         <% print.forEach(function (user) { %>
            <tr>  
                <td><%= user.username %></td>  
                <td><%= user.password %></td>
            </tr>                                   
         <% }) %>
         </tbody>
    </table>   
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I can't name a variable return, so I just named it obj and changed the other "return" 's necessary but left most of the code as is, but it still tells me  "print is not defined". Do I maybe need to loop the result argument in the connection query? Weird thing I already did but maybe I did it in the wrong way or something.

Comment: I updated the answer. After the `res.render('print', obj);` add `console.log(obj);` for show the value of the consulting. After post here the result...

Comment: Ahh, you don't need the loop the result, this way works.

Comment: Ok, so I think we're getting somewhere. I added the console.log() and it prints out: { print:
[ 
{username: 'Tony', password: 'Lee'},
{username: 'Mark', password: 'Douglas'},
{username: 'Marshall', password: 'Hamilton'}
],
_locals() }

Comment: I updated the answer, see `<%= print[0].username %>`.

Comment: Yes, perfect it works. Thanks so much man. But how can I now print everything that's in my table? I figured this out but it doesn't work as I want it to because it prints the username and password of every object alone in a new line what I want is to have ( Username <space> Password): <% for(var i=0; i<print.length; i++) { %>
    <% for(x in print[i]) { %>
     <p><%= print[i][x] %></p>
    <% } %>
   <% } %>
So am I on the right track or is their an easier way or something?

Comment: Bravo man, seriously. Thank you very very much. Works exactly as I want it to.

Comment: @LucasCosta where did you mention the name of the html page where the data is to be shown?

Comment: @SwapnilB. when we're using Express, the `render` will look for into the *views* directory, so if it has an HTML page called **print** into **views** the data will be rendered.

Comment: @LucasCosta oh, that makes complete sense. Thank you :)