# How should routing html pages be done for website?

Tags: express, routes

I'm using MEAN stack. For example, if I click on a item, how does it route it's item page like *****.com/item/[id]? How does it go to that item page for that id? Is this done using node and express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the route and send file, somelike this...

```
app.get('/item/:id', function (req,res){
    console.log(req.params.id); be show the param id
    res.sendFile('page.html', {id: req.params.id});
)};
```

[More aboute routes](http://expressjs.com/en/guide)

Comment: how do access the id variable on the frontend then?

Comment: see that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32628453/get-mysql-data-in-node-js-express-and-print-using-ejs/32630437#32630437

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you need to understand routing mechanism of single page applications. Now you should be aware that your root path that is '/' will be served by express

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '../public') });
});
```

As soon as your index.html is served to the client, Angular will take over all the routing. You must use a routing solution for that(ui state or ngRouter). if you want to go to a particular route in angular containing some id you can create a route like this(assuming you are using ui-state router)-

```
$stateProvider
  .state('user', {
      url: "/user/:id",
      templateUrl: "/angular/users/views/user.html",
      controller: "UserCtrl"
   });
```

In your html file you will write -

```
<a ui-sref="user({id: userId})">
```

Here userId is the id you want to pass to the route.

Hope it helps!